# Как правильно написать join в linq?

Tags: c#

У меня есть список `List<VisitorRequestDto>` и словарь `Dictionary<Guid, (string, string, string, string)>`

```
public class VisitorRequestDto
{
    public uint Num { get; set; }
    public List<VisitorDto> Visitors { get; set; }
}

public class VisitorDto
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
}
```

Я хочу сделать join и вытащить данные из словаря, `VisitorRequestDto`, `VisitorDto`. Вот такие данные должны вернуться:

```
[Num, Id, string, string, string, string]
```

У меня получается возвращать только со словаря и Visitors, делаю я так:

```
var subjects =
        from visitor in visitorRequests.SelectMany( x => x.Visitors )
        join archiveEvent in events on visitor.Id equals archiveEvent.Key
        select new Output
        {
             SubjectId = visitor.Id,
             Entry = archiveEvent.Value.minEntry.Value.Timestamp,
             Exit = archiveEvent.Value.maxExit.Value.Timestamp,
             EntryTerritory = archiveEvent.Value.minEntry.Value.TerritoryIDs,
             ExitTerritory = archiveEvent.Value.maxExit.Value.TerritoryIDs
        };
```

Не хватает `num`, но я не совсем понимаю, как мне его достать. Если добавить from visitorRequests после join, то он вообще будет странно джойнить и вернет совсем не то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так

```
    var dict = new Dictionary<Guid, (string, string, string, string)>();
    var visitorRequests = new List<VisitorRequestDto>();

    var subjects = visitorRequests
        .SelectMany(x => x.Visitors.Select(z => new
            {
                Num = x.Num,
                Id = z.Id,
                Entry1 = dict[z.Id].Item1,
                Entry2 = dict[z.Id].Item2,
                Entry3 = dict[z.Id].Item3,
                Entry4 = dict[z.Id].Item4,
            })).ToArray();
```

Comment: Только в таком случае, мы будем ловить ошибку, если id в словаре нет

Comment: Ну исключите таких `x.Visitors.Where(z=>dict.ContainsKey(z.Id)).Select(…`

Comment: спасибо! очень плохо знаю linq, поэтому для меня как-то неочевидно